# Prove $\log(n) = O(n)$ using induction

Tags: algorithms, induction, logarithms, asymptotics

I am using the lecture notes [here](https://larc.unt.edu/ian/books/free/lnoa.pdf) on page 19 (Algorithm Notes 1) example 1 is the inductive proof of

$\log(n) = O(n)$.

I understand the base case but I don't understand the rest of the example.

> Example: $\log(n) = O(n)$. Claim: For all $n \geq 1$, $\log(n) \leq n$. The proof is by induction on $n$. The claim is trivially true for $n=1$, since $0<1$.
>
> Now suppose $n\geq 1$ and $\log(n) \leq n$. Then $$ \log(n+1) \\ \leq \log(2n) \\ = \log(n) + 1 \\ \leq n+1 \quad \text{by the inductive hypothesis}.$$

I need help understanding how

$\log(n + 1) \leq \log(2n)$.

I don't get where the $\log(2n)$ came from.

Comment: $log(n) \gt log(2)$ for $n \gt 2$ and $log(\alpha * \beta) = log(\alpha) + log(\beta)$. These two give you the desired answer.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! If you can type up your entire question so it's self-contained in your question statement, more readers will be be more likely to help you (as opposed to having them hunt down the problem statement/proof every time they look at your question).

Comment: It might help to look at it like $n+1 \leq n + n = 2n$, which uses the fact that $n \geq 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n + 1 \le 2n \implies \log(n+1) \le \log(2n)$

Comment: did they just get the 2n only because n+1 < 2n, could  I for any reason say 3n or 4m then in that case?

Comment: @KyleCalica-St They chose $2n$ as it is a simple upper bound, and since $\log$ is usually base 2 for computer science, it is very convenient. You can choose $kn$, where $k$ is a constant.

Comment: Awesome thank you

Comment: Just a remark: a constant $\geq 2$.